# adding values using load data

Tags: mysql

I have a table with composite primary key. I am trying to load data from a text file.
I need the new value to be added to the original value of the table.

```
drop table if exists load_data;

CREATE TABLE `load_data` (
  `zoneid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creativeid` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`zoneid`,`creativeid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

insert into load_data values (1200, 2200, 4), (9200, 9200, 91);

mysql> select * from load_data;
+--------+------------+-------+
| zoneid | creativeid | count |
+--------+------------+-------+
|   1200 |       2200 |     4 |
|   9200 |       9200 |    91 |
+--------+------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

# cat abc1.txt
1200    2200    8
9200    9200    7
```

The following load data is adding 5 counts to the new value and not the orginal count for unique combination of primary key columns.

```
load data infile 'abc1.txt' replace into table load_data (zoneid, creativeid, @a) set count = @a+5 ;

mysql> select * from load_data;
+--------+------------+-------+
| zoneid | creativeid | count |
+--------+------------+-------+
|   1200 |       2200 |    13 |
|   9200 |       9200 |    12 |
+--------+------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I try to add the value to the original count value of respective zone and creative id columns, I get NULL instead of the new total.

```
mysql> load data infile 'abc1.txt' replace into table load_data (zoneid, creativeid, @a) set count = @a+@count ;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 2  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from load_data;
+--------+------------+-------+
| zoneid | creativeid | count |
+--------+------------+-------+
|   1200 |       2200 |  NULL |
|   9200 |       9200 |  NULL |
+--------+------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expected results:

```
mysql> select * from load_data;
+--------+------------+-------+
| zoneid | creativeid | count |
+--------+------------+-------+
|   1200 |       2200 |    12 |
|   9200 |       9200 |    98 |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because REPLACE forces to remove records firstly.

To handle it, you can temporary add new field and load `count` data from the file. Then write UPDATE table to calculate `count` field, and then remove temp. field.